# How to convert string to number in java ? But i am not looking for hashCode as it wont give unique number. at least i want math logic for same

Tags: java, math, mathematical-optimization

Hi I want to convert string to some unique number in java. 
Exmple:  "Production-0-1" to 100021
"Process-23-30" to 12310
And all return number has to be unique. 
I dont wanted to use hashCode as they can return duplicate like "Aa" and "BB" has same has code.
Let me know math logic to create this is no method available.

Comment: i mean from any string to unique number.

Comment: Does `System.identityHashCode()` work for you?

Comment: change it to `char` array and replace every char with its equivalent number, that will give you a unique value.

Comment: And that was going to be my second suggestion: `new BigInteger( string.getBytes( "UTF-8" ) ).toString()`

Comment: @ The Scientific Method: this will not work if string is with more than 15-20 char

Comment: No it works for any size string, up to the limit of memory.

Comment: @markspace good answer. but you have posted it as a comment. answers should be posted as answers.

Comment: @PatrickParker It is not a good answer.  I strongly suspect the OP wants something completely different.  I'm just trying to steer the OP into realizing what they actually want.

Comment: @markspace thank you if i use 
first System.identityHashCode("Route-1"); and System.identityHashCode("Route-2"); then i changes order first Route-2 and then Route-1 then its giving me different answers. I want  same value whenever and however i call that

Comment: System.identityHashCode(); will not work . as i need always unique value and that to be same when i pass same string at any place throughout application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String random = "Production-0-1";
    String bi = new BigInteger(random.getBytes("UTF-8")).toString();
    BigInteger numBig = new BigInteger(bi);
    System.out.println(numBig);
```

Based on @markspace comments, I tried the following and every time it produces random unique number but beware if you have a very large String and a limited memory space then the output may go out of bound.

Comment: thanks but i have more than 300000 strings for which i want to get unique numbers and really it will consume more memory. will this give me always same value ?

Comment: @gajananbejgamwar Yes one thing which is guaranteed that it will always give you same value. But memory consumption will be high. My suggestion would be that you try this once.

Comment: @gajananbejgamwar this will work but might not save any memory. I suggest using compact Strings in Java 9+ which could halve the memory usage.

Comment: @gajananbejgamwar if each String uses 64 bytes of memory this is less than 20 MB which isnt a lot of memory these days.

Comment: @PeterLawrey the string is being encoded as UTF8. so one byte per char when possible. That is the same as Compact Strings, right? (then of course memory is wasted when converting the integer to a String.)

Comment: one more question can i revert this number to string.